# Concatenate the result of a SELECT Query into one NVARCHAR Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temporary table named `#temp` with one column:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (column nvarchar(50));
```

And it contains an unlimited number of rows (it can be any where from 0 results to a 100.

I want to select all the results of the table in one line with commas (,) between them

```
Column
--------|
 Result1    
 Result2   
 Result3 
 Result4    
 Result5  
 Result6   
 Result7    
 Result8
```

The select query would give me the following result:

```
"The results are: Result1, Result2, Result3, result4, Result5, Result6, Result7, Result8"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL 2017 has the built-in [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function, but you can use the snippet below in earlier versions of SQL.

```
DECLARE @concat NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SELECT @concat += ', ' + [col] from @data
SELECT 'The results are: ' + ISNULL(STUFF(@concat, 1,2,''),'')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`string_agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select string_agg(column, ', ')
from #temp;
```

Comment: it seems to be inefficient with more than 20 results STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.

Comment: somehow the function isn't recognized by my SQL as well 
'string_agg' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @HoussemTimoumi . . . The answer points to the SQL Server documentation for the function.  It is definitely supported, but you may be using an older version of SQL Server.